# */_MEI*/VCRUNTIME140.dll is either not designed to run on windows or it contains as error when trying to run .exe created by pyinstaller

Tags: python

I've been searching through a lot but not one is related to my problems, mostly their problems is vcruntime140 missing.
But I'm not, here my problems:

I am created an .exe file using pyinstaller from a .py (which is my small python game program) in my Windows 10 when I'm trying to run the program it gives me this error:
'''c:\user***\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI***\VCRUNTIME140.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or
it contains an error. Try installing the programs again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support. Error status 0xc00000d '''

which the second message appears after click ok on the first message:

'''Error loading Python.DLL 'C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI***\python38.dll
LoadLibrary. The parameter is incorrect'''

updating Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 RC is not an option since after I've had been tried but got warn that I've had installed.

I have one picture non-related to python is using for the logo on my programs, I linked using relative path, the source code quite long so I no posting here, but I've added this code related to that picture:

```
def resource_path( relative_path ):
        absolute_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
        root_path = os.path.dirname( absolute_path )
        base_path = getattr( sys, 'MEIPASS', root_path )
        return os.path.join( base_path, relative_path )
img = tkinter.PhotoImage( file = resource_path('./picture/lottery.gif') )
```

Answer (score 0):

'''Hey I managed to solve these problems'''

```
please allows me plant some riddle if you did tries:
    -restart your computer
    -updates Windows update retribution
    -reregistering VCRUNTIME140.DLL
    -starting to reformat your PC( STOP! )
before you try these:
    make sure you are using 64bit python on your 64bit OS
    make sure your .exe is the same path as your .py which pertains to some 
    external source to operate your programs
```

'''that solve my problems, hope this help the most of yours problems'''